# Trying to calc diff of now and last time stamp and update timestamp

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do some basic estimating of how long users spend on a site. I have a simple polling script in javascript that hearbeats out to a php script. I'm trying to do the following in one sql statement:

- calculate the difference between now and the last updated_on field (which is a datetime field ) and add it to the current active_time field (which is just an integer)
- Then update the updated_on to reflect that the record has been updated

This is the sql I'm trying to use;

```
UPDATE login_log 
SET active_time = active_time + ( SELECT  TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( NOW(), updated_on ) ) ),
updated_on = NOW()
WHERE user_id = ? && session_id = ? AND status = 'active'
```

Question 1 - I'm assuming I can update updated_on and still use it to calc the difference and not have a race condition, but can someone confirm or tell me that doesn't work?

Question 2 - I must be doing something else wacky because after abit, the active_time is way off as in it thinkgs it's been going for hours when it's only been 20 minutes. Not really scope of this quesiton, but if anyone sees anything quickly that is wrong, I'd appreciate knowing ....

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the wrong way to go about this.  I would simplify it having two fields, `created` and `updated_on`, which I would call `last_updated`.  To calculate the current time on the site you would simply subtract the created value from the current time.  Presumably, you want some permanent record as well.  That comes from the `last_updated` field, which is updated each time a request from the user is seen (including your heartbeat).  You simply update it with the current time.  The difference between `created` and `last_updated` becomes your permanent record of the time on site.